# Protractor not waiting for page load Angular4

Tags: angular, protractor

I have been running protractor but have to put in a

`browser.sleep(1000)` and a `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` to make it run, especially after a login or so, otherwise it doesn't get the page.

I know that `browser.sleep` isn't a recommended practice which is why I ask.

Comment: And after the `browser.sleep` your tests execution is canceled, because the page isn't loaded, am I right?

Comment: No it carries on, because I use browser.sleep(1000), but what I have read they say I should preferably not use browser.sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `browser.sleep` is when an action of your software needs more time then specified your test will fail.
Another problem is if you're using a lot of `browser.sleep`s your test can be very slow, because the test is waiting for the whole time you have specified in `browser.sleep`.
But there are of course situation where you need to use `browser.sleep`, but there are not many, in my opinion.

A better solution to wait for elements is the `browser.wait` function with  [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions). `browser.wait` gets a method as argument, which would return true if a specific condition becomes true, and it waits as long as the function is not resolved or the timeout is reached.

Example:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var button = element(by.id('submitLogin'));
// Waits max. 10 seconds for the button to become clickable
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button), 10000);
```